# Wrong keyboard-layout using Synergy and i3

Tags: keyboard-layout, i3, synergy

I have a setup where my keyboard-layout won't work in i3 using Synergy (Swedish). When I switch from i3 to Mate there's no problem with the keyboard (still using Synergy).

**Synergy server** 
 Windows 10 64bit. Swedish language

**Synergy client** 
Ubuntu Mate 64bit. Swedish language running i3. The swedish special characters like å ä ö won't work.

Comment: Do äöå work in `i3` without synergy?

Comment: Yes it does @njsg

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an i3 way of setting the right keyboard layout but, since I've never used i3, I can't help with that. A more generic approach is to use `setxkbmap`:

```
setxkbmap se
```

You can either run the command manually, or add it to i3's startup file. Alternatively, you could also put it in `~/.profile`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried that already, setxkbmap se and for some reason that's not the correct layout @terdon